# Scrollbar apperars in Chrome when there is nothing to scroll

Tags: css, scrollbar

I am using [this](https://html5up.net/dimension) template for a small portfolio webpage. The problem is that when the website is opened in Chrome, a scrollbar always appears on the main page as shown below:

[image: Screenshot]

This does not happen in Firefox, Edge and IE. [Here](https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/dimension/) is a link to the demo of the template and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mxspdw92/1/) a jsfiddle with the CSS. Both display the unnecessary scrollbar when Chrome is used. I tried adding the following line to the html file but it didn't help:

```
.content {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I hope that somebody can help me out here. Thanks!

---

Edit: The problem is somewhere here, but I cannot figure out a way to fix it.

```
#wrapper {
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        -moz-flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        -moz-align-items: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        -moz-justify-content: space-between;
        -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        -ms-justify-content: space-between;
        justify-content: space-between;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 4rem 2rem;
        z-index: 3;
    }

        #wrapper:before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
        }
```

Comment: I am lost here. Can anybody please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Chrome and I'm not seeing any scrollbar when I visit your demo. Or the fiddle for that matter

Answer (score 0):

Is there something overwriting your call to hide the scroll bar elsewhere on the page? E.g:

```
    overflow: auto;
```

Or is it perhaps another element on a page with a width/height (e.g image or div element) that is causing the issue?

Another option is to go to the inspector and start deleting items until you find out which one is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure why this occurs (can indeed see the same issue) but it's super easy to workaround by simply applying `overflow-y: hidden` to the body

```
body{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```